# How to know if QLayoutItem is hidden by scroll in QScrollArea?

Tags: qt, visible, qscrollarea, qgridlayout

I have a similar question as asked in [How to know if QListWidgetItem is hidden by scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992034/how-to-know-if-qlistwidgetitem-is-hidden-by-scroll) and the answer to that question didn't fix my problem.

Basically I have a QScrollArea having QGridLayout. This layout has many QToolButtons. Based on some condition, all these QToolButtons need to be updated. To update all of them always is not so efficient, so I want to update only the buttons which are visible in the current active window. How can I achieve this? isVisible() doesn't help here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QWidget::visibleRegion()` to check whether widget is visible and paint events can occur for widget.

```
if (!button->visibleRegion().isEmpty())
{
    //button is visible
}
```